# href not working inside updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="divFilters">
                <div class="subHeaderWrapper">
                    <span class="subHeaderLeft">
                        <img id="imgCtrlContainer" onclick="toggle_visibility('divContainer1','imgCtrlContainer','span_min.png','span_max.png','true');" name="Expand and Collapse1" alt="Expand / Collapse" src="../Style/UX/Images/span_min.png" style="display: none;" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="widgtTitle">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFilters" EnableTheming="false" runat="server" Text="Filters"></asp:Label>
                    </span>
                </div>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div class="subHeaderWrapper" id="divSubHeaderWrapper" runat="server">
    <span class="subHeaderLeft"></span>
    <span class="widgtTitle">
        <asp:Label ID="lblObservation" EnableTheming="false" runat="server" Text="Observation"></asp:Label>
    </span>
    <a **href="#divFilters"** id="filterAnchor" class="filtersPopup" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img style="border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; border-top: medium none; border-right: medium none" id="util1" class="filterIcon" onmouseover="mouseOverUtl('util1')" title="Filter" onmouseout="mouseOutUtl('util1')" name="Util1" runat="server" alt="Utility" src="../Images/icon_dash_filters.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<asp:Griview...>
</asp:Gridview>
```

Above is my code written in the asp:UpdatePanel tag.While going from the anchor tag to the div "divFilter" the `href="#divFilters"` mentioned is not working.The same page when taken to another aspx page without giving updatepanel works fine. But I need to get it done under UpdatePanel only

Comment: Since you can't really rely on W3C Validator, you should be very carefull with html standards. What I mean is you are definitively missing the `</div>` closing tag for `<div id="divFilters">`. You should take care of indenting your code to prevent this errors. Tell me if it resolved your problem.

Comment: I have modified the code by closing the div tag but still error is not resolved yet.

Comment: I think you `href` tag doesn't throw **postback**, so doesn't lead you to the  appropriate link. I never done this with a link, but you should consider using `<asp:Link>` and see if `autoPostback` proprety is set to `true`.

Comment: How to make the href throw postback, do I have to write some code for it in codebehind.